# 4x4 number grid with one empty cell

Tags: pattern

Can you guess what comes in place of the question mark?

[image: Table]

Here's a text-based version of the table:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1536 | 48 | 96 | 3 |
| 384 | 192 | 24 | 12 |
| 768 | 96 | 48 | 6 |
| 192 | ? | 12 | 24 |

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's:

> $384$. Starting from the top-left, go down and do a U'y at the bottom, go up, do a U'y at the top, you get: $1536, 384, 768, 192, ?, 96, 192, 48, 96, \dots$, which is divide by $4$, multiply by $2$, and repeat.

Comment: You got it. It's correct

Answer (score 4):

It is

> $384$. In every row, the product of first two numbers is $73728$ and the product of last two numbers are $288$.

Comment: The answer is correct. But there is a much simpler way to find the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

> 384

Explanation:

> alternating rows of the same column are halved or doubled

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the pattern finding, this answer:

> Think of how the horse moves in chess. Let's call the final position the horse can go be P. So the bottommost 24 has 24 on its P on the left hand side. The bottommost 12 has 12 on its P on the RHS. The 192 has 192 on its P on RHS so the ? has 192 on its P on LHS. It moves up too. 48 and 96 have 48 and 96 respectively at their Ps on their LHS and RHS respectively.

Comment: It is even simple to find it. Think **moving up and down**.