# Fill the grid- 4.0

Tags: number-sequence

Grid again !!!

Can you find what comes in place of '***?***' ?

[image]

HINT 1

> It starts from o at the left

HINT 2

> $135^o$

HINT 3

> [image]

In text:

```
5234
2112
06?7
0964
```

Also Try:

[Fill The grid - 3.0](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83687/fill-the-grid-3-0)

[Fill the grid - 2.0](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83629/fill-the-grid-2-0)

[Fill the grid (pattern)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83605/fill-the-grid-pattern)

and an unanswered question

[Find the celestial body](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83930/find-the-celestial-body)

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is

> 0

Reason

> For the 1st column, (∑yellow boxes-∑blue boxes=**3**)
>  $$$$
>  For the 2nd column, (∑yellow boxes-∑blue boxes=**2**)
>  $$$$
>  For the 4th column, (∑blue boxes-∑yellow boxes=**5**)
>  $$$$
>  The only number left is **4** so that for the 3rd column, (∑blue boxes-∑yellow boxes=**4**), which is 1+6-3-**?**=4.
>  $$$$
>  Therefore, **?**=0

Comment: Your logic is nice (+1) but it's not the correct answer. Sorry.

Comment: Added a hint, give another try.